# How to make a picture look like it's torn off?

Tags: images, photo-editing, paint.net

How do I cut off the boundary of a picture all zig zag like it is in this picture

[image: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2010/08/31wpanswers.PNG]

Or in this one

[image: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/shivprasadk/aspect-oriented-programming-in-C-Sharp-net-part-ii/Images/attributes.jpg]

I have Paint.NET, a free image editing software. How can I do this in Paint.NET?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this tutorial: http://cscroman.wordpress.com/2011/09/05/paint-net-torn-paper-effect/

In short

- Create a layer on top filled with white.
- Add a third layer on top of all of those.
- Draw the line of your torn paper on this layer in black.
- "Merge Layer Down" on layer 3. Layers 2 and 3 will be merged.
- Duplicate this layer
- Gaussian blur the lower of these two layers
- On the other one, select the area you want to show using the magic wand tool.
- Invert your selection and clear
- "Merge Layer Down” again
- Still with the Magic Wand, select the area of the image you will show
- "Merge Layer Down” one more time.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to edit the shadow later, the torn page effect can be achieved using this plugin:

- [Drop Shadow Plugin for Paint.net](http://paintdotnet.forumer.com/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=22881&hilit=Drop%20Shadow)

If you don't know how to install plugins [you can learn here](http://boltbait.com/pdn/InstallingEffects.asp).

What you first need to do is recreate the torn border of the page, erasing some parts manually. Then go into **Effects > Object > Drop Shadow** and change the values to the ones you prefer.

[Source](http://forums.getpaint.net/index.php?/topic/15602-how-to-make-text-with-a-dropshadow-in-5-steps/)